# Measure-Command: measure python script execution time

Tags: python, windows, powershell, execution-time

I found that I can measure execution time on Windows with this command:

```
Measure-Command {start-process python .\script.py -Wait}
```

and it works great. Unfortunately, when I try to run a script which takes some (positional and optional) arguments, I get an error message, with

```
Measure-Command {start-process python .\script.py file.txt 100 -Wait}
```

I get the error:

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'file.txt'.

Without Measure-Command everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong? How to measure execution time for scripts which take arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
Measure-Command {start-process python -ArgumentList (".\script.py", "file.txt", 100) -Wait}
```